Issue in RedisInsights
So, i am using Redis in my project, Initially i was using Redis-cli for those commands and all. But later i needed a GUI tool to manage all things. SO, i installed RedisInsights.
I added the same connection in my Redis insight. Initially, the key that i was getting in my cli "userfeed" i got that on the Redis insight too. But when i added a new key on cli or in Redis insights, it is not being reflected on the other.
I deleted the key "userfeed" on my RedisInsights. But is still in my cli.
I think there is some issue in syncing, but i cannot pinpoint what the issue is?
Did anyone else faced this issue?
